# Why does adding an attribute link to my image move my image?

Tags: html, flexbox, href

I'm trying to insert two images that are stacked vertically (flex-column) which I can do if both images aren't within an attribute tag. However, when I do put them in a tag, the pictures offset slightly to the right as shown in this image in mobile view.
[image]

Here, the top image takes you to a link on click, but the bottom doesn't. The HTML I used has this form.

```
    
                <div className={isWideScreen ? "horizontal-flex basic-container" : "vertical-flex basic-container"}>
                    <a href="https://www.website1.com/"><img className="set-pic-size" src={pic1}/></a>
                    <img className="set-pic-size" src={pic2}/>
                </div>
```

The associated css is here for mobile view.

```
.basic-container {
    justify-content: center;
}

.set-pic-size {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to put the second image inside **<a href="">**.

Comment: I did that for the purpose of this example. When I do include the second image inside an <a href"">, the second image also becomes off-centered.

Answer (score -1):

Do not place the images inside an anchor element; instead, try adding the `href` to the image itself. Anchor elements are text which have an underline and look like links; `href=""` can be used to set the redirect link on click for any element.

Remove the `A` element and copy/paste the `href` attribute to the image.

Comment: This fixes the formatting! But I don't go to another page when I click on the image.
`<img href="website" className="set-pic-size" src={pic1}/>`

Comment: It should work, are you putting an actual website in the href="" attribute?

Comment: Ok, forget what I said, use the A tag however give the A tag the href and the .set-pic-size class. Remove the .set-pic-size class from the image. And it is not ClassName="", it is class=""